# How to open a new file from the command line with Inkscape

Tags: command-line, inkscape

I can't find how to open a *new* svg document with Inkscape, simply from the terminal.

If the document specified as argument (or via `-f`) does not exist, there is just an error saying it doesn't exist, and then it opens an unsaved new document.

I tried using the verb `FileSaveAs` like this for example:

```
inkscape --verb FileSaveAs mynewfile.svg
```

but FileSaveAs does not take arguments, it just opens the graphical window for this action.

I might be persnickety, but I would find it more convenient to be able to create a new file directly from the command line instead of having to launch this window and click to the right directory...

Comment: `touch  mynewfile.svg; inkscape mynewfile.svg`?

Comment: I thought about that, but a totally empty svg file causes an error.

Comment: Hi @PlasmaBinturong posted. Please mention if all is clear.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yep very clear thank you, I guess I will work with that for now. Don't know if the developpers have their reasons for this behavior, but maybe that's worth submitting a bug report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my surprise, there seems to be no option in Inkscape to produce a new file from cli!

#### How to create the option?

As always, if it doesn't exist, it can be made:

1. Open `Inkscape`, create a new file `drawing.svg`
2. Save this file anywhere
3. Copy the code below into an empty file, save it as `newinkscape` (no extension) in `~/bin`. Create the directory if it doesn't exist yet.

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   sample="/path/to/drawing.svg"
   dr=$1

   cp "$sample" "$dr"
   inkscape "$dr"
   ```

   ***Make the script executable***
4. Replace in the line:

   ```
   sample="/path/to/drawing.svg"
   ```

   The path by the path to your sample file.

Log out and back in, now:

```
newinkscape /path/to/newfile.svg
```

will open a new empty `Inkscape` file, saved in the location you used in the command.

Comment: Excellent answer. 2022, and it's still the best I think. you should add few lines to check if $dr exists though. It's dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I've been wondering about this same thing for years (especially since `touch  mynewfile.svg; inkscape mynewfile.svg` causes `InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /path/to/mynewfile.svg ; ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!`) - and finally, after consulting https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line, I found it:

```
inkscape --without-gui --actions="file-new; export-area-page; export-filename:test.svg; export-do;"
```

For instance, to test under Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ inkscape --version
Inkscape 1.0.1 (1.0.1+r73)
    Pango version: 1.40.14

$ ls -la test.svg
ls: cannot access 'test.svg': No such file or directory

$ inkscape --without-gui --actions="file-new; export-area-page; export-filename:test.svg; export-do;" 2>/dev/null && ls -la test.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1134 Sep 15 05:53 test.svg

$ cat test.svg 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg10"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   viewBox="-1 -1 1 1">
  <metadata
     id="metadata16">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs14" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="640"
     inkscape:window-height="480"
     id="namedview12" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome. I need to try on a recent Inkscape, because I have 0.92.5, where `--actions` is not available. There are `verbs` though, but this is not sufficient for the question.

Answer (score 1):

With Inskcape 1.0:

```
inkscape --actions="file-new;export-filename:output.svg;export-do"
```

or, if you want, you can use a template for the new file:

```
inkscape --actions="file-new:template.svg;export-filename:output.svg;export-do"
```